# Implement debounce: how to make three invocations result in one effective call?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

How can I invoke three times a function with a setTimeOut but just print it once after 100 milliseconds??

This is the definition of `debounce` that I have to implement:

> Debounce ignores the calls made to it during the timer is running and
>   when the timer expires it calls the function with the last function
>   call arguments, so I want to achieve that with Javascript

A function will be debounced as follows:

```
receivedEvent = debounce(receivedEvent, 100)
```

My attempt:

```
function debounce(func, timeInterval) {
  return (args) => {
    setTimeout(func, timeInterval)

  }
}

function receivedEvent() {
  console.log('receive')
}

receivedEvent();
receivedEvent();
receivedEvent();
```

But this still generates 3 outputs. I need it to only produce one output according to the requirements.

Comment: So there's already a `debounce` function, but not with the correct content. Where is this function coming from?

Comment: The question and provided code do not add up.

Comment: Debounce ignores the calls made to it during the timer is running and when the timer expires it calls the function with the last function call arguments, so I want to achieve that with Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your attempt you did not call `debounce`, but just called your own function `receivedEvent`. Maybe the site where your attempt is tested will do this for you, but we cannot know this from your question. Just make sure it is called.

To test the requirements you need to use a better use case: one based on a function that receives *arguments*. This is needed because you must prove that the debounced function is called after the timeout with the *last* passed arguments.

The key to this pattern is to use variables within a closure:

```js
function debounce(func, timeInterval) {
    let timer;
    let lastArgs;
    return (...args) => {
        lastArgs = args; // update so we remember last used args
        if (timer) return; // not ready yet to call function...
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            func(...lastArgs);
            timer = 0; // reset timer (to allow more calls...)
        }, timeInterval);
    }
}

function receivedEvent(arg) {
    console.log('receive ' + arg)
}

receivedEvent = debounce(receivedEvent, 100)

receivedEvent("a");
receivedEvent("b");
receivedEvent("c");

// Output will be "c" after 100ms
```

Note that the question's definition of "debounce" deviates a bit from its usual definition, where the first invocation actually calls the function *immediately*, and only then starts the timeout (cooldown-period).